# Angular 2 router resolve server request before opening a component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have a `BookDetailComponent` component which is mapped for an url `/books/:id`. Is there any way in angular 2 router to make sure that this component is opened only after the `Book` with given `id` is retrieved from server?

I am looking for similar functionality like [ui-router resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) in Angular 2 router.

```
/*** BookComponent ***/
@RouteConfig([
  {path: "/books/:id", component: BookDetailComponent, as: "BookDetail"},
])

export class BookComponent {
}


/*** BookDetailComponent ***/
export class BookDetailComponent {

  book:Book;

  constructor(private bookService:BookService,
              private routeParams:RouteParams) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.routeParams.get("id");
    this.bookService.getBook(parseInt(id))
      .subscribe(book => this.book = book.json());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by implementing the `OnActivate` interface and returning a promise of the object you are waiting to load:

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way we can resolve for `Observable`?

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about that but you can test it, or you can call the .toPromise() method of the observable.

Comment: Hey, do you know if the resolved value can be injected into the component?

Comment: you don't have to inject it, by implementing that method inside the component you are already inside the component, just set the resolved value to a component's property.

Comment: "If you want to prevent the route from being rendered until the promise is settled you need to use the CanActivate decorator." - brandonroberts https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6611

Comment: The related information on the otherwise-usually-accurate Auth0 site is not correct: https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/