# Observable type error: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs

In my Angular 2 application, I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.

This is a very simple component, just trying to get a bare minimum to work here.  It hits my API controller (curiously multiple times), and it appears to hit the  callback after an object is returned.  My console.log outputs the object I would expect.  Here is the full error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_About_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:10897:14), <anonymous>:31:26)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8824:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8807:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8877:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8811:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesContentChildren (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8871:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8808:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8877:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8811:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChanges (http://localhost:55707/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8796:12)
```

The service (about.service.ts):

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {AboutModel} from './about.model';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AboutService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    get() {
        return this._http.get('/api/about').map(res => {
            console.log(res.json()); // I get the error on the line above but this code is still hit.
            return <AboutModel>res.json();
        });
    }
}
```

The Component (about.component.ts):

```
import {Component, View, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {AboutModel} from './about.model';
import {AboutService} from './about.service';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'about',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, AboutService],
    templateUrl: 'app/about/about.html'
})

export class About implements IAboutViewModel, OnInit {
    public about: AboutModel;

    constructor(private _aboutService: AboutService) {}

    ngOnInit() {    
        this._aboutService.get().subscribe((data: AboutModel) => {
            this.about = data;
        });
    }
}

export interface IAboutViewModel {
    about: AboutModel;
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="~/lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2/bundles/router.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        map: {
            rxjs: "lib/rxjs"
        }
    });
    System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: Bind to about?.title. It's more forgiving when about is undefined

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Please include your view and model next time (app/about/about.html and about.model).

If you are returning an **array**, you can use the [asyncPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html), which "subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes" hence the view will be updated with the new value.

If you are returning a **primitive type** (string, number, boolean) you can also use the asyncPipe.

If you are returning an **object**, <strike>I'm not aware of any way to use asyncPipe</strike>, we could use the async pipe, in conjunction with the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) `?.` as follows:

```
{{(objectData$ | async)?.name}}
```

But that looks a bit complicated, and we'd have to repeat that for each object property we wanted to display.

As @pixelbits mentioned in a comment, you can `subscribe()` to the observable in the controller and store the contained object into a component property. Then use the safe navigation operator or NgIf in the template:

service.ts

```ts
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  // we need to import this now

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private _http:Http) {}
  getArrayData() {
    return this._http.get('./data/array.json')
      .map(data => data.json());
  }
  getPrimitiveData() {
    return this._http.get('./data/primitive.txt')
      .map(data => data.text());   // note .text() here
  }
  getObjectData() {
    return this._http.get('./data/object.json')
      .map(data => data.json());
  }
}
```

app.ts

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>array data using '| async':
      <div *ngFor="let item of arrayData$ | async">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    <div>primitive data using '| async': {{primitiveData$ | async}}</div>
    <div>object data using .?: {{objectData?.name}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="objectData">object data using NgIf: {{objectData.name}}</div>`
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, MyService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _myService:MyService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.arrayData$     = this._myService.getArrayData();
    this.primitiveData$ = this._myService.getPrimitiveData();
    this._myService.getObjectData()
      .subscribe(data => this.objectData = data);
  }
}
```

data/array.json

```
[ 1,2,3 ]
```

data/primitive.json

```
Greetings SO friends!
```

data/object.json

```
{ "name": "Mark" }
```

Output:

```
array data using '| async':
1
2
3
primitive data using '| async': Greetings SO friends!
object data using .?: Mark
object data using NgIf: Mark
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LpEDM9ZhG7ui8gf3q5wG?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Mark, here you are using ? (Elvis operator) for the front end. What if you need the data in your service to make another call? I have a service.getId().flatMap( id => return service.getUser(id);).subscribe( data => console.log(data))  but my data is returning undefined even though it gets logged in the service.

Comment: @AdamMendoza, have the service return the flatMap and then subscribe to it in the component.  Also use `?` in the view/template, since the data is resolved asynchronously.  If this isn't clear, I suggest that you post a new question showing your service and component.

Comment: I have been searching and searching and yours is by far the clearest answer! thanks a million dude

Comment: if you do not like using the [safe operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) you take the about object `as` another object - see [angular-ngif-async-pipe](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe)

Comment: What do you do if you have something like `*ngFor="let post of ((postsFiltered$ | async)['Original-content'])"` ? `)?['Original-content']` is not a valid syntax.

Answer (score 33):

It looks like you have referred to `about.title` in the view `about.html` but the `about` variable is instantiated only after the `http` request is completed. To avoid this error you can wrap `about.html` with `<div *ngIf="about"> ... </div>`

Comment: I've done this and still get the error.
First element in about.html: <div *ng-if="about">
Also added to about.component.ts:
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],

Comment: I needed to add the following line in ngInit to get this to work:
this.about = new AboutModel();
Seems less than ideal, that and the ngIf solution.  Wish I could bind to an Observable from my html template, can I?

Comment: @RyanLangton Glad you got it working. Anyway, you can try `OnActivate` https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html . Related on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734367/angular-2-router-resolve-server-request-before-opening-a-component

Comment: Thanks for this, it was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 20):

The previous answer is correct.
You need to check if the variable is defined before use it in your template. Using HTTP request it need time to define it. use *ngIf to check. Example is provided from angular with https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html
and example is http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

```
<div *ngIf="hero">
  <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
<div>
```

You can check app/hero-detail.component [ts and html]