# Assign to variable in .map .subscribe angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a property in class Product

```
Quantity: number;
```

I have a GET function like so:

```
 getData(value: string) {
        return this.fooService.getFoo(value)
            .map(response => response)
            .subscribe(result => this.product = result);
    }
```

How can I assign a value to **this.Quantity** before the method returns?

Comment: You shouldn't really do that. Instead of doing a `.subscribe()` have the `getData()` function return the `Observable`. Then either assign the subscription in a lifecycle hook like `ngOnInit()` or better yet just `.map()` to a property as an `Observable` and use [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html). If you are going to subscribe, then not only should it be in an "init" hook, but you should also keep the handle to the subscription in order to release it on component destroy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable type error: cannot read property of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at this