# Angular 2 - how to hold template rendering till data recieved from @ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

In my ngOnInit function (in vehicle.component.ts) I recieving data from server and then dispeching that array of vehicles to the Store. After that I subscribing to the store data to find the vehicle. But when I calling **vehicle.find()**, my template is already rendered with errors - of course no vehicle found... What should I do to fix this?

```
ngOnInit() {
let id = this._route.snapshot.params.id ? this._route.snapshot.params.id : null;
if(id){ // Передан id       
  this.newVehicle = false;     
  // Если не были загружены данные, загрузить 
  if (!this._vehicleService.dataIsLoaded){ 
    this._vehicleService.getVehicles().subscribe(vehicles => {
      this._store.dispatch({type: INIT_VEHICLES, payload: vehicles});   
      this.vehicles.subscribe(vehicles => {
        this.vehicle = vehicles.find(item => item.id === Number(id))
      }); 
    })
  } else {
    this.vehicles.subscribe(vehicles => 
      this.vehicle = vehicles.find(item => item.id === Number(id))
    );  
  }   
  if(!this.vehicle) 
    console.error('No Vehicle found!');
} else { // id пустой, создаем новый объект      
  this.vehicle = new Vehicle(this.getLastVehicleId()+1, null, null);      
}
```

}

My template (vehicle.component.html):

```
<h3>{{ vehicle.name }}</h3>
<div><label>Id: </label>{{ vehicle.id }}</div>
<div>
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="vehicle.name" placeholder="name" />
</div>
<p>
  <button (click)="saveVehicle()">Back</button>
  <button class="abort" (click)="removeVehicle()">Remove</button>
</p>
```

Full source code is here: [GitHub](https://github.com/antonpegov/angular-fl/tree/46c5f3bfb8e54368ca3d0dc128e11e7633242486),
last version running [on GitHub Pages](https://antonpegov.github.io/angular-fl)

PS

To reproduce the error you should navigate to vehicle info page and psess F5.
Not reproducing on ghpages, it just crashing )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable type error: cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Comment: My question is more about @rxjs/store.

Comment: Yes, I've fix it by adding <div *ngIf="viewReady"></dir> wrapper, and opening this flag after recieving data from the store. But I'm not shore it is the right way...