# Angular 2 - Viewing a Single Record of Data

Tags: javascript, angular

*I am new to Angular so I am having trouble figuring out how to form my questions for what I am trying to accomplish, but here it goes.*

I have a component that is fetching a single user record from a service. I then want to display those user details on my UI. In other parts of my code, they have always been multiple records so I have used `*ngFor` and looped over the array of data. However, since this is just a single result, I am not too sure how to accomplish this.

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { UserRecord } from '../shared/user-record.interface';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-view-record',
    templateUrl: './view-record.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./view-record.component.css']
})
export class ViewRecordComponent implements OnInit {

    private record: UserRecord[];
    private errorMessage: any = '';
    private loaded = false;
    private RecordID: number; // User ID of who we are looking at

    constructor(private _crudService: UserService,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        // Get the userID from the activated route
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            this.RecordID = params['id'];
        });

        // Call our service and pass the userID
        this._crudService.getRecord(this.RecordID)
            .then(res => {
                this.record = this._crudService.record;
                return this._crudService.getRecord(this.RecordID);
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(this.record)
                this.loaded = true;
            })
            .catch(err => { console.error(err); });
    }

}
```

**Service:**

```
getRecord(userID: number) {

        const headers: Headers = new Headers({
            "Authorization": this._frameworkService.getSessionInfo().token
        });
        return new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
            this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/fetchRecord', { "userID": userID }, { "headers": headers })
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe((data) => {
                    if (data) {
                        this.record = data;
                    }
                    resolve(true);
                });
        });
    }
```

**Interface:**

```
export interface UserRecord {
    RecordID: number;
    QID: string;
    FavoriteColor?: string;
    FavoriteNumber?: number;
    FavoriteActor?: string;
    MetaInsertUTC: string;
    MetaUpdateUTC: string;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    NTID: string;
}
```

**Service Result:**

```
[  
   {  
      "RecordID":"55",
      "QID":"Q00019204",
      "FavoriteColor":"Blue",
      "FavoriteNumber":"6",
      "FavoriteActor":"Bob",
      "MetaInsertUTC":"2017-06-29 18:47:01.750",
      "MetaUpdateUTC":null,
      "FirstName":"Jim",
      "LastName":"Bobs",
      "NTID":"bobby"
   }
]
```

In my Component HTML, I have tried `{{record.FirstName}}` but receive the error of `ViewRecordComponent.html:16 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined`.

Since this isn't a set of data results, I don't see how `*ngFor` would be applicable in the use case.

I assumed that since my component is storing the data in the `record` object, I should be able to access that from the UI? The `console.log` shows all of the correct data points.

How would I reference the users `FirstName` in my component HTML? Hopefully I'm on the right path at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response seems to be an array with an object, so `record.FirstName` doesn't exist, but `record[0].FirstName` does.

And when it comes to the view, remember to use either the safe navigation operator or `*ngIf` so that you do not run into undefined issues like mentioned by DeborahK. [Observable type error: cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Furthermore just some suggestion on how to handle http in Angular... I would do something like the following...

```
getRecord(userID: number) {
    const headers: Headers = new Headers({
        "Authorization": this._frameworkService.getSessionInfo().token
    });
    return this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/fetchRecord', { "userID": userID }, { "headers": headers })
       .toPromise()
       .then(res => res.json()[0]) // get the object only
       .catch(err => { console.error(err); });
}
```

and component:

```
this._crudService.getRecord(this.RecordID)
   .then(res => {
       this.record = res;
   });
```

But that's totally up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from Http is asynchronous. This means that when the page is first displayed, the data is not yet there.

There are several ways to resolve this:

One option is to use the "?" (safe navigation) operator: `{{record?.FirstName}}` This better handles nulls. See this link for more information: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Another option is to use *ngIf around your HTML code. `*ngIf='record'`

So when your page is first displayed, it will not generate an error that record is not yet set. As soon as the data is retrieved, the binding will notice the change and update the UI appropriately.

Here is what one of my service methods look like:

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And here is the call to that service:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Notice that the subscribe is in the component that calls the service, not in the service itself.

Comment: So I tried to add `<tbody *ngIf="loaded">` which wraps my data. I set this to true in the componet service call with `.then(res => { this.loaded=true;})`. While the error is no longer thrown in the console, the datapoint is also not shown. A little progress I suppose.

Comment: Why use a separate property? Just check your 'record' property. Then you don't need to worry about setting/clearing the loaded property.

Comment: Good point, I changed that. I will play around with the result set now that the error is gone and try to determine why its not showing up. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: My service looks a little different. I added it to my answer above.