# HTTP get service - cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a service like so..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class WeatherProvider {
  loading: Boolean = true;
  private url: string = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1';

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  getWeather(){
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

I'm using the service like this...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ModalController, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WeatherProvider } from '../../providers/weather/weather';

@Component({
  providers: [WeatherProvider],
  selector: 'page-display-route',
  templateUrl: 'display-route.html',
})
export class DisplayRoutePage {

  weather: any;
  constructor(public weatherProvider: WeatherProvider ) {

              this.getWeather();
  }

  getWeather() {
    this.weatherProvider.getWeather().subscribe(d=>{
      this.weather = d;
    })
  }
```

And in my html I attempt to access the returned data like so...

```
<ion-content>
<h1>{{weather.cod}}</h1>
</ion-content>
```

But I receive the error

```
Cannot read property 'cod' of undefined
```

If I `console.log()` my data then I can see the returned response. I'm guessing this is because my weather variable is undefined at the point I'm accessing it but I'm unsure of the right way to go about this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable type error: cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Comment: Please make an attempt to even find an answer before posting. Just googling that error gives you plenty of Q&A...

Comment: I did attempt to find an answer but couldn't  find an ionic specific answer so I thought there may be some better practice when using ionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ngIf` to handle undefine:

```
<h1 *ngIf="weather">{{weather.cod}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use safe operator

```
<ion-content>
<h1>{{weather?.cod}}</h1>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too but for now I'll use the *ngIf solution

Answer (score 0):

I think response may be returned but returned value is not assigned to weather. So {{weather}} is not defined it results its property not defined. 
Try to set value of {{weather}}.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `weather` as `object`.

```
weather: any = {};
```