# Cannot read property 'title' of undefined, but title is displayed

Tags: angular

I'm new with angular 4 , and I'm trying to build my first application.

The title is displayed in the screen but get this error in the **console**   :

[image]

This is line 26 in the html file:

```
<h1>{{result.title}}</h1>
```

This is **TravelDetailComponent**:

```
export class TravelDetailComponent implements OnInit {

result: string[];
id: number;

constructor(private http: Http, private globals: Globals, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}


ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      console.log(this.id);
  });
  this.http.get(this.globals.baseUrl + 'travels/' + this.id)
      .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(result => this.result = 
result);
}

}
```

why the title is displayed in the screen but I get this error in the **console** and how can I solve it ?

Comment: You get the error when the component is created, but later after the `this.http.get` completes the title is shown.

Comment: Error says that there is problem on line 10 in html. Without posting.html of your component it is hard to say where the problem is.

Comment: post your HTML here

Comment: this is line 26 in the html file : <h1>{{result.title}}</h1> . the title exist and it is not null and he is displayed , so why it says undefined property title ?

Comment: If you read our answers below you'll see that you need the elvis operator. In other words `<h1>{{ result?.title }}</h1>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable type error: cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll run into this A TON in angular unless you familiarize yourself with the [Angular Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax). Specifically the use of the `*ngIf` and the elvis operator `?`.

For example, if you are just wanting to display the title you could do the following to make sure the page doesn't try to render the title until it has one.

```
<h1 *ngIf="title">{{ title }}</h1>
```

Furthermore if you have an object with a property you can forgo the `*ngIf` and check to make sure the object has resolved. For instance let's say you save all of the page's data into the `page` object and like above, want to display the title.

```
<h1>{{ page?.title }}</h1>
```

If you wanted to be really safe, you could still wrap it in an `*ngIf` statement that checks the title specifically, but usually if you have data within the page object, it's safe to assume there's a title in there.

Comment: this is line 26 in the html file : <h1>{{result.title}}</h1> . the title exist and it is not null and he is displayed , so why I need to add safe operator "?" or yousing "if" , can you explain it to me please ?

Comment: Your template is checking for the title multiple times, probably faster than you can even recognize. So it fails a couple times when the page renders (yes it's null for a little bit), and then finally gets the value once the API call completes and returns a value to the observable.

Comment: The safe operator just helps the page not try to retrieve values until they are truly available, it saves errors, and in some cases prevents much more problematic scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **`safe operator`** in HTML to check if the value is present, this will avoid the above error if the value is not present

```
<h1>{{ yourObj?.title }}</h1>
```

Comment: this is line 26 in the html file : <h1>{{result.title}}</h1> . the title exist and it is not null and he is displayed , so why I need to add safe operator "?" , can you explain it to me please ?

Comment: Because you didn't map the result(object) from back end to any TypeScript model on client side. Please refer here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score -1):

You have probably not called the body-parser middleware. Add this to your code below the app initialization.

```
// body-parser

app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```