# Cannot read property of undefined Angular 4 Typescript

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, data-binding

I have been trying to sort this out for a while now and could definitely use some help. 
I am trying to display the question I got from the server and stored locally. But When i try to display the question that i got it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'question' of undefined
```

Here's my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Questionnaire</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="Question" align="center">
 <h2 [innerHTML] = "q.question"></h2>
</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

Here's typescript that is for sure returning values because i can log them and so I checked:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-questionnaire',
  templateUrl: './new-questionnaire.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-questionnaire.component.css'],
  providers: [NewServerRequestsService]
})

export class NewQuestionnaireComponent implements OnInit {



  q: any;
  sub: any;
  id: number;
  cQuestion: number;
  score: number;
  qNumber: number;

  constructor(private serverService: NewServerRequestsService, private 
route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){} 


  static questionTime = performance.now();  
  onload()
  {
    console.log(NewQuestionnaireComponent.questionTime);
    // this.ButtonClicks();    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
      // fetch the file and get next Question
      this.id = +params['id'];

      if (localStorage.getItem('q') !== null) {
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('q'))
        this.qNumber = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('qNumber'))
        this.q = data.results[this.id - 1]
      } else {
        this.serverService.getQuestion()
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('q'))
        this.qNumber = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('qNumber'))
        this.q = data.results[this.id - 1]
      }

    });
  }

    }

  }
```

Here's the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class NewServerRequestsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getQuestion()
  {
    return this.http.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=30")
    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    data => {
        // shuffle questions
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length - 1; i++) {
            var j = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (data.results.length - 
i));

            var temp = data.results[j];
            data[j] = data.results[i];

            data[j].incorrect_answers.push(data[j].correct_answer)

            data[i] = temp;

        }
        localStorage.setItem("q", JSON.stringify(data))
        localStorage.setItem("qNumber", JSON.stringify(data.length))
    },
    err => console.error(err)
    )

}

}
```

Here's where the data gets fetched:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  providers: [NewServerRequestsService]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private QuizService: NewServerRequestsService, private route: 
ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.QuizService.getQuestion();
  }
  ngOnDestroy() { }

}
```

Comment: Try stripping out all non-essential code to provide a minimal example that reproduces your problem. That way people will more likely try to help you, and the question will be more helpful to others with a similar problem.

Comment: You've (at least) got some trouble with asynchronicity, both in template and TS. when calling `this.serverService.getQuestion()` you cannot be sure that the data is set in localStorage when you are fetching it: `var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('q'))` in your `else`. I'm 99% sure that the data isn't there. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined to understand asynchronicity.

Comment: @dskrvk Thanks for letting me know. I've stripped the unnecessary stuff.

Comment: @AJT_82 Ive made some edits. Please go through the same.

Comment: @AJT_82 is correct, it is an issue with asynchronicity.  When you render the dom, `q` is not yet defined.

Comment: I am going through the links. Thanks for helping. Will post when i make all the adjustments. :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Even though i have gone through the links i still am not being able to get it done and despite trying promises and observables im getting the same error. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

this error occurs because `q` is undefined when rendering the view , try using safe navigation by using `?` :

```
<h2 [innerHTML] = "q?.question"></h2>
```

Comment: Nothing came up. I mean no error but no question. Please let me know what it means. Thanks

Comment: when you use safe navigation : `q?.question` , it means : check if `q` is not `undefined` then look for `question` inside `q`

Answer (score 0):

initialize q: any = {} if it's an object, [] if array ;)
tell me now what console.log(q) show

Check q in your ts or on your html `<h2 *ngIf="q" ...`

Comment: it says undefined

Comment: Ok so you never get or change the value in your component that fetch the data, when you get them, it is asynchronous so you must verify if it exists & create an empty objet you can show until you get the data ;) Then try q = this.QuizService.getQuestion(); si that you can use q and display it :)