# Angular httpClient get single object typeError _co.object undefined

Tags: angular, get, httpclient, typeerror, ngfor

I use Angular5 with httpClient to request a rest api.
My issue is I perfectly get lists of objects but I can't obtain a single object.
I use modules for this module I have a service in which I have my call to the api-rest:

```
    getUser(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<IUserComponent>('apiAddress/getbyid?id=' + id);
    }
```

In the component I call it

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getUser(this.id);
    }
    getUser(id): void {
    this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data;
    });
    }
```

And I call user in my template:

```
    <p>
      {{user.name}}
    </p>
```

When I do that I get nothing displayed and the error

```
    TypeError: _co.user is undefined
    ERROR CONTEXT Object { view: Object, nodeIndex: 12, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object }
```

I can get something displayed but I still get the error if in the service I say I want an array

```
    getUser(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<IUserComponent[]>('apiAddress/getbyid?id=' + id);
    }
```

and when I call it I say

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getUser(this.id);
    }
    getUser(id): void {
    this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data[0];
    });
    }
```

And finally if I call the service:

```
    getUser(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<IUserComponent[]>('apiAddress/getbyid?id=' + id);
    }
```

and call it

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getUser(this.id);
    }
    getUser(id): void {
    this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(data => {
        this.users = data;
    });
    }
```

I can display the data with *ngFor and don't get any error.
I don't very understand why.

In the hero tutorial of Angular 
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6
They wrote this service to get all:

```
      getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
      return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
      tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
      );
      }
```

and this one to get a single one

```
    getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Hero>(url).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`fetched hero id=${id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero>(`getHero id=${id}`))
    );
    }
```

where the pipe is used to do several action so here tap and cathError and tap I am not sure to understand correctly what it is used for there is a doc 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.2/src/operators/tap.ts#L14
but it seems to be used for debug.

Comment: if you were to look at the example html, you would also see that they are using `<div *ngIf="hero">` in template :)

Comment: Also apparently you have not initialized `user`, therefore it's undefined. I suggest you also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined Not looking too closely on your code, so hopefully there is no additional issues :)

Comment: IUserComponent? it's a strange name for an interface that must be an interface of only data. NOTE: Use {{user?.name}} or initialize the variable

Comment: I don't understand why I would need to initialize user, if I don't need to initialize users.
If by initializing you mean give it an initial value I initialize non of them if you mean define their type it is done for both of them.

Comment: The difference between why needing to initialize `user` but not `users`, is tho both are `undefined`, but you are trying to read **property** `name`. And there is no such property on `undefined` :)

Comment: thanks AJT_82 the *ngIf corrected my error in the console so I can get my value but I have to retrieve an array and then say I take the first element. If I want to get the object directly I get nothing if I do an alert to get the name I get undefined so I guess it is because it is not initialized as you say. thanks again :)