# Angular ASP.NET: Http Get Web Api call works but no values shown by Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple WebApi created in asp.net core which is as follows:

```
[HttpGet("GetHomePageData")]
        public IActionResult GetHomePageData()
        {
            HomePageData HomePageData = new HomePageData()
            {
                BookName = "Test Book",
                AddressCount = 55
            };
            return Ok(HomePageData);
        }
```

In angular, i try to call it as follows:

```
constructor(public http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') public baseUrl: string) {

        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/GetHomePageData') 
            .subscribe(res => this.homePageData = res.json() as HomePageData);   
}
```

In my view, i try to display HomePageData as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="homePageData">Total Address = {{ homePageData.AddressCount }}</div>
```

When run in Chrome, the Api call works fine and the page loads fine with no errors. However, no values are displayed, as in the 'homePageData.AddressCount' is empty.

Anybody know what happened here?

FYI, I've followed the SO answer in [Observable type error: cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Thanks!

Comment: what do you see if you put `{{ homePageData | json }}` in your template?

Comment: i see { "bookName": "Test Book", "addressCount": 55 }

Comment: hey why is it small caps a?

Comment: the first letter in 'addressCount' is now small caps.... weird.. but it works now!! thanks

Comment: Also you could have checked that by looking a the network tab in your browser dev console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET serializes with camelCase

instead of `AddressCount` use `addressCount`