# Angular/Typescript - Solve Async in Array

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

We have 2 arrays **Speisekarte** and **Essensplan** - I want to call the method **printName**, to print out the name, I get from the ID.

The problem is, "name" is always undefined.

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

How can i fix async in methods in templates?

**Template** (Async in printName(essenName) )

```
<div *ngFor="let i of essensplan"> <br />
  <div><b>Woche : {{i.id}}</b></div> <br />
  <button *ngFor="let id of i.essenProWoche" (click)="print(id)">Gericht 
** {{printName(id)}} ** </button>
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log("ngOnInite essensplan.component")
  this.getSpeisekarte();
  this.getEssensplan();

}

printName(id: number) {
  this.essenName = this.speisekarte.find(i => i.id == id ).name

 getSpeisekarte(): void {
  this.essenService.getSpeisekarte()
  .subscribe(speisekarte => this.speisekarte = speisekarte);
}

getEssensplan(): void {
  this.essensplanService.getEssensplan()
    .subscribe(essensplan => this.essensplan = essensplan)

}
```

Comment: In your template *essenName* is not defined. do you mean `{{printName(id)}}` ?

Comment: oh yes, sorry. Will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is possible to delay the entire component until both HTTP calls have completed. Instead of that, you can modify `printName` to handle the case where `this.speisekarte` hasn't been loaded yet. Then, tell the component to reload once it has.

**Component**

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("ngOnInite essensplan.component")
  this.getSpeisekarte();
  this.getEssensplan();
}

printName(id: number) {
  const match = this.speisekarte.find(i => i.id == id );
  return match ? match.name : "";
}

getSpeisekarte(): void {
  this.essenService.getSpeisekarte()
  .subscribe(speisekarte => {
    this.speisekarte = speisekarte;
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
  });
}

getEssensplan(): void {
  this.essensplanService.getEssensplan()
  .subscribe(essensplan => { 
    this.essensplan = essensplan;
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
  });
}
```

---

Now, regardless of the order the HTTP requests complete, the templates will not error (although the names will be blank if `getEssensplan` finishes before `getSpeisekarte`

---

Note: I changed `printName` to return a value, since that will be necessary to display it

Comment: YOU'RE A LEGEND. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Use Observables for your problem. They will significantly reduce and improve your code. Angular has a buildin pipe called async-pipe which subscribes as long as the component is alive.

```js
export class MyEssenComponent {
  essensPlan$: Observable<Essensplan>;
  speisekarte$: Observable<Speisekarte>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.essensPlan$ = this.essensplanService.getEssensplan();
    this.speisekarte$ = this.essenService.getSpeisekarte();
  }

  get name(id: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.speisekarte$.pipe(
      filter(speisekarte => speisekarte.id === id),
      map(speisekarten => speisekarten[0] ? speisekarten[0].name : '')
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can easily rewrite your template to

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of essensplan$ | async"> <br />
  <div><b>Woche : {{i.id}}</b></div> <br />
  <button *ngFor="let id of i.essenProWoche" (click)="print(id)">
    Gericht ** {{name(id) | async}} **
  </button>
</div>
```

Also I recommend to choose more meaningful variable names as the are totally irritating. E.g. you chose *essenProWoche* attribute for an array of IDs, or just *i* as variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) "The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks."

```
<div *ngFor="let i of essensplan | async "> <br />
```

or use NgIF operator to show safely the view.

Please check the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined) for the same problem.