# Displaying Observable Object Values correctly

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey so Im getting started with Angular more and more and im doing my first Project now, I fetch data from my Database via my Service Method:

```
  getPost(postID: String) {
    this.postDocument = this.db.doc('posts/' + postID)
    return this.postDocument.valueChanges()
  }
```

I call that method inside my component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentPost = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.fs.getPost(params.get('id')))
    )
  }
```

This works so far but I dont really understand how I can display the data in my HTML? This here for example brings me that titel is null even when its displayed correctly.

```
<div>
  post-read-page works!
  <h1 *ngIf="currentPost">{{ (currentPost | async).titel }}</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Exact Error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'titel' of null`

Comment: Use `{{ (currentPost | async)?.titel }}`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34772772/1009922).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `currentPost` can be also null so you need to handle also the null case in the template correctly to not get the error.
As already suggested in the comment you can use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) (?.) to handle this.

Then your binding looks like this:

```
<div>
  post-read-page works!
  <h1 *ngIf="currentPost">{{ (currentPost | async)?.titel }}</h1>
</div>
```