# Visual Studio Code in Angular: Cannot read property of undefined, How Do I fix?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

How do I take datatype of any in Angular and convert to known data type?

I have a service below, receiving some service data, and want to convert to productDataClass which has `{productId: int; productName: string;}`

At the very least, I at least want `productId` which is an integer.

Sending data similar to this resource,

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

```
public productDataClass: ProductDataClass;

this.productService.currentMessage.subscribe(currentMessage => {
  this.productDataClass = currentMessage
```

I then tried this, which is not working  copyFromMessage is `any` type,

```
this.productService.currentMessage.subscribe(currentMessage => {
  this.copyFromMessage = currentMessage;
  this.productData = this.copyFromMessage.value;
  this.testString= this.productData.productName;
```

**Error:**

> Cannot read property 'productName' of undefined

**Basic Service:**

```
export class ProductService{

  private messageSource = new Subject();
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(currentMessage) {
    this.messageSource.next(currentMessage);
  }
}
```

Looking in this resource also:
[Observable type error: cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Screenshot of actual items:

CurrentMessage has actual data, following lines show undefined,
[image]

['value'] is still giving error

[image]

Comment: Hi mate, did you try `this.productDataClass = currentMessage as { productId: int,  productName: string } `?

Comment: can you add what's inside currentMessage when you are inside the subscription?

Comment: `this.productData = this.copyFromMessage.value;` are you sure here you will get productName or not?

Comment: hi @GaurangDhorda that also gives me undefined error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with Visual Code Debugger Chrome Extension. One can use command `debugger` between line of codes, and the debugger values will display properly.
All other answers in this post are also valid.

```
this.productService.currentMessage.subscribe(currentMessage => {
  this.copyFromMessage = currentMessage;
  debugger;
  this.productData = this.copyFromMessage.value;
  this.testString= this.productData.productName;
```

In this line of code, Chrome Extension thought for some reason `.this` is referring to the subscription rather than the class component.

You can use `_this` to access the class component.

Comment: You should be able to use `_this` to access the class component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript runtime error.

The `changeMessage()` is not called with an object of this structure `{value: {productName: ...}}`

Comment: hi htn, well I am using a generic service for different data types

Comment: hi, your object does not contains `value` key.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9fa6nf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**your productDataClass is**

```
export class Productdataclass {
       productId: number;
       productName: string;

     get _productId() {
         return this.productId;
     }
     set _productId(id:number){
        this.productId = id;
     }
    get _productName(){
        return this.productName;
    }
    set _productName(name: string){
       this.productName = name;
    }
}
```

- **Your Service is**

  ```
      import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
      import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

      @Injectable()
      export class DataService {
             private messageSource = new Subject();
             currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
             constructor() { }
             changeMessage(currentMessage) {
                 this.messageSource.next(currentMessage);
             }

       }
  ```
- **In app.component.ts** , you can call method of changeMessage() here in button click.

  ```
     export class AppComponent  {

          public productDataClass: Productdataclass =new Productdataclass();
          public copyFromMessage: Productdataclass = new Productdataclass();
          public testString : string;

          constructor(private data: DataService){ }

          ngOnInit(){
               this.productDataClass._productId = 1 ;
               this.productDataClass._productName='toothBrush';
               this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(data =>{
                        console.log(data)
                        this.copyFromMessage = data['value'];
                        this.testString = this.copyFromMessage.productName;
                        console.log(this.testString);
               })
         }
         call(){    
            this.data.changeMessage( {value:this.productDataClass} )
         }
    }
  ```

Comment: hi, the second line, "this.copyFromMessage = data.value;", Property 'value' does not exist on type 'unknown'  on data.value

Comment: have you cheked stackblitz link, there working fine

Comment: This is just type-script lint error. You can correct using this.`this.copyFromMessage = data['value'];` a lil bit syntax changed here.

Comment: hi @GuarangDhora, ['value'] is still giving me an error, screenshot above

Comment: Have you checked again in StackBlitz link for the same ?

Comment: hi , I also placed answer below, and gave points to your answer, thanks